# PHP remove all _GET variables from a URL/string apart from the first.

Tags: php

How can I remove all GET variables from a string apart from ?v=

E.g: the below url would remove &feature=related

> [www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDZ_NhSSiq8&feature=related](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDZ_NhSSiq8&feature=related)

Would this be safe to simple remove everything after the first `&` or is there a more robust way of doing this in PHP?

```
$safe_url= substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "&"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do something like this:

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDZ_NhSSiq8&feature=related";
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $youtube);
$safe_url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $youtube['v'];
echo $safe_url;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 0):

Well since $_GET is an array
you could recraft the URL  using $_GET[v]

something like

$newURL = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'.$_GET[v];

header("Location:".$newURL."");

not sure if thats 100% correct syntactically but you get the idea

Comment: sadly this wouldn't work because the user is entering the URL into a form.

Comment: its essentially the same answer as Kyle .. he just spoke more eloquently :D